# how to ignore comma in string array in apex

Tags: string, array

I have this String Array
[Burlington Textiles Weaving Plant Generator,Tim,Barr,"1,056.00",Burlington Textiles Corp of America];

How can I Ignore that Amount comma inside the " " .

Answer (score 0):

You can use String replace method.

> String s2 = s1.replaceAll(",", "");

Above method will replace all commas with a blank value. So your 1,056.00 will become 1056.00 .